# Pandas: Convert certain numbers in a dataframe to integer

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

I need to merge multiple CSVs containing text and numbers and create an Excel workbook with each CSV forming a separate worksheet. Although it's not strictly a dataframe, I decided to use Pandas library since it provides a lot of useful functions for reading and writing from CSVs and xls files.

I'm using the following line of code to create a writer object:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
```

Now, when I do read_csv on individual CSV files, it's reading everything as a string and storing even the numbers as string and that's messing up TCL script that processes this merged xlsx.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)
```

Is there a way to convert these numbers to int before doing the to_excel?

The purpose here is to simply merge all the CSVs into an excel workbook without modifying any data.

Note: I know that xlsxwriter engine supports converting strings to numbers but I can't use xlsxwriter since it doesn't support editing an existing workbook.

I tried doing this, but it doesn't help:

```
 for col in df:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors='ignore')
```

EDIT: Eventually, I just lived with this issue and handled in the post processing. None of the suggestions (as of Jul 2020) worked.

Comment: round(col,0).astype(int) If I recelall right.

Comment: @pinegulf, I tried this: 
`for col in df:
   df[col] = df.round(col,0).astype(int)
`
But I got this error:
`ValueError: the 'out' parameter is not supported in the pandas implementation of round()`

Comment: CSVs store all data as strings so you always need to convert. Pandas does have some heuristics that do this for you but you should always be prepared to do this yourself. FWIW going straight from CSV to Excel with openpyxl will be faster than using Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase:

If you have specified columns that contain numeric values then this should be better (because it would either be a Number or None).

`df.col = pd.to_numeric(df.col)`

If you want the whole DataFrame to look for numeric, then try this

`df.col=  df.col[df.col.str.isnumeric()].astype('int', errors = 'ignore')`

Comment: Hi @ahsen-nazir, I tried the following:
`for col in df:
   df[col] = df[col][df[col].notnull()].astype('int')
`

But, I'm getting this error:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AAAA'`

AAAA is the first element in the dataframe.

Comment: df[col]= df[col][df[col].str.isnumeric()].astype('int', errors = 'ignore')